# Batch file can't find specified path when run from excel hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch-file, network-drive

I have an excel file that has a list of IP addresses and I have linked a batch file that runs a simple ping test and outputs the results to a text log.

When I run the file from the network location it runs no problem. But when I run the excel (Also located in the same directory)...the ping returns "The system cannot find the path specified"

**Note** - It is returning Ping as what cannot be found. Not the file output.

Anything I'm missing?

```
ping -n 1 **EXAMPLE** >> Logs\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_Test.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Would you prefer the answer here or at StackOverFlow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977112/batch-file-cant-find-specified-path-when-run-from-excel-hyperlink) where you posted the same question?

Comment: Stack. I'll remove this one.